# JavaScript lock function to prevent recursion (browser freeze/performance)

Tags: javascript, performance, freeze

For my Keyboard Power Keys script I've implemented a feature per request to enable the `up`/`down` arrow keys to give focus to checkboxes (up for the checkbox in the row above and down for the checkbox on the row below) on a table representing emails (apparently like the old Yahoo Classic Mail though I was unaware of that feature before they stopped allowing access). This feature works great with one exception: when I hold the up arrow key down (versus tap, tap tap) it ends up locking up Firefox when it reaches the top checkbox; the more I hold it down the more likely it'll KO the browser and I'll have to manually terminate the process.

I'm open to a variety of approaches though anything involving a global variable *must* utilize the `option` class.

Frameworks are *explicitly* forbidden, we're talking real code and performance.

The option class, not necessary unless your approach requires a global variable...

```
var option = new function() {this.name = '';}
```

Here is the function that handles various key press events...

```
function keyPressed(evt)
{
 var e = evt || event;
 var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

 if (powerKeysEnabled)
 {
  switch (key)
  {
   case 38://Up Arrow
   if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='a' && e.target.previousSibling && e.target.previousSibling.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='input' && e.target.previousSibling.type=='checkbox' && e.target.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='tr')
   {
    var t;
    if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='table') {t = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;}
    else if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='table') {t = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;}

    var tr = t.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var i=0; i<tr.length; i++)
    {
     if (tr[i]===e.target.parentNode.parentNode)
     {
      i--;

      if (tr[i])
      {
       var a = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('input');

       if (a[0] && a[0].type=='checkbox')
       {
        a[0].focus();
        break;
       }
       else
       {
        i--;

        if (tr[i])
        {
         var b = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('input');

         if (b[0] && b[0].type=='checkbox')
         {
          b[0].focus();
          break;
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

Anyone interested in how the script works should realize that I do XHTML as `application/xhtml+xml` and am extremely articulate about proper code. It should also be noted that I replace uncustomizable input checkbox elements with anchors and hide checkboxes (via CSS `position`, *not* `display`) and visually replace each checkbox with an anchor element. Note that whitespace is important to an extent in how the script interprets the XHTML, do not edit for the sake of others. Here is a sample XHTML table this works with...

```
<table summary="This table displays emails from the currently choosen folder.">
<colgroup style="width: 5%;"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width: 20%;"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width: 50%;"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width: 25%;"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width: 5%;"></colgroup>
<thead><tr><td colspan="5"><span>Delete, move, other email features...</span></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="" /></td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr></thead>
<tfoot><tr><td></td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> /td></tr></tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr id="mail_inbox_208_row"><td><input type="checkbox" value="" /></td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
<tr id="mail_inbox_207_row"><td><input type="checkbox" value="" /></td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an exclusion for the `id` of the check-all checkbox and it no longer locks up; second if condition...

```
if (
e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='a' && 
e.target.id!='mail_inbox_all_img' && 
e.target.previousSibling && 
e.target.previousSibling.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='input' && 
e.target.previousSibling.type=='checkbox' && 
e.target.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='tr'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'yielding' using setTimeout with a delay of 0? Something like the following:

```
function keyPressed(evt)
{
 var e = evt || event;
 var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

 if (powerKeysEnabled)
 {
    setTimeout(function() {
      //perform work here
    }, 0);
 }
}
```

Comment: Tried that per your suggestion though it did not work. For clarification I used 10 milliseconds instead of 0.

Comment: Next thing I would try is [throttling](http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls) to 5 or 10 times a second